# css-loader, export css modules mapping

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, css-modules, postcss-loader

When using postcss-loader (with postcss-modules) in webpack, I get a .json file for each .scss file I have with the css-module hash mappings. If I use css-loader with `modules: true`, I do not get such mapping file. Is it possible to also get one with that loader?

The issue is really that when using postcss-loader, I can for some reason not import scss files in my .js files. If I use css-loader instead, that is possible.

I would need to both import the scss files in my .js files with css-modules correctly imported, and have the mapping files (.json) generated, which I am using in my php files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using `css-loader`.

At the end, I could do it using [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) and [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules)

First, `postcss-modules` convert the .css/.scss files to hash in base64. Also, it creates `.json` file per each .css/.scss file where it contains the mapping for each class name to his corresponding hash name.

Then, `posthtml-css-modules` takes the html files where you use the .css/.scss files and convert the html elements that uses the classes named with `css-modules` to his corresponding hash name defined in the `.json`.

**webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = function (options) {
    ...
    return {
       ...
       module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                    loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'html-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'posthtml-loader',
                            options: {
                              config: {
                                ctx: {
                                  include: {...options},
                                  content: {...options}
                                }
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')],
                    use: [
                        'to-string-loader',                  
                        'css-loader',
                        'postcss-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'assets/[name].[hash].[ext]',
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(eot|woff2?|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
                    use: 'file-loader'
                }

            ],
        },
    };
};
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer'),
        require("postcss-modules")({
            generateScopedName: "[hash:base64:5]"
        })
    ]
}
```

**posthtml.config.js**

```
module.exports = ({ file, options, env }) => ({
    plugins: [
        require('posthtml-css-modules')(file.dirname.concat('/').concat(file.basename.replace('.html','.scss.json')))
      ]  
});
```